# simple_form association field not pre-selecting selected elements

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, associations, simple-form

I have a `Message` data model in Rails with a "virtual" association. That is, a method that returns a collection of "associated objects", but it is not an actual association in the ActiveRecord sense.

```
class Message
  def recipients
    @recipients
  end

  def recipients=(arr)
    @recipients = arr
  end
end
```

The thing with simple_form is that, when I try to show a `association` field, it fails because there's no `:recipients` association:

```
= simple_form_for(@message) do |f|
  = f.association :recipients, collection: Recipient.all
```

The solution seemed then simple, I went on to use a `f.input` with the `as: :select` option:

```
= simple_form_for(@message) do |f|
  = f.input :recipients, as: :select, collection: Recipient.all
```

And this works fine, except for the fact that it does not automatically detect the values already in `@message.recipients` so that the elements appear pre-selected when the form is rendered.

If `Message#recipients` were an actual association, in the ActiveRecord sense, then `f.association` in the form would do this as well. But for reasons that go beyond the scope of this question, I can't make it as an actual association.

The question then is, can I achieve `f.input :recipients, as: :select` to pre-select the selected elements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, this is embarrassing. Just after posting this, I came up with an idea that ended up solving the problem:

```
class Message
  # ...

  def recipient_ids
    # ...
  end

  def recipient_ids=(arr)
    # ...
  end
end
```

I added the `recipient_ids` getter and setter, **in addition** to the association getter and setter that I had before.

Then I updated the form input field to refer to `:recipient_ids` instead of `:recipients`:

```
= simple_form_for(@message) do |f|
  = f.input :recipient_ids, as: :select, collection: Recipient.all
```